# Connection Reference in Service Project Editor of z/OS Connect EE

Tags: cics, zos-connect-ee

Please help me to understand the connection Reference that we give the service project editor of z/OS connect EE.

Will it be used when establishing a connection with CICS region from z/OS connect EE server?

Adding the image.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connection reference is used to establish the connection to CICS from z/OS Connect. The value should match the `id` attribute of the `zosconnect_cicsIpicConnection` element in `server.xml`.

Example:

```xml
<zosconnect_cicsIpicConnection id="cicsConn" host="localhost" port="1091"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

The connection reference can alternatively match the id of a `zosconnect_cicsConnectionGroup` element in `server.xml`. If required, the connection reference can be dynamically changed at runtime using a policy.